# iphone UIViewController does not show data passed from the first view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

The purpose of this app is to retrieve the data selected on `UITableCell` and pass that on to a new view controller. All is well until the user selects the cell. The next view controller is loaded but the screen is black. 
On that screen i have a `UIImageView` and `UILabel`. I have a `UINavigationController` set up in the storyboard. I am trying to get the image and text selected on the first screen to the respective objects on the next screen. I have retrieved the data from a database and have loaded it to the first screen.

Here is my code on my `storedetail.h` which is a subclass to a `UIViewController`,

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIImage *storeImage;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UILabel *storeCode;
```

Here is my code where i am calling the nextviewcontroller which is `ShowStores.m` which is a subclass of a `UITableView`,

header code ,

```
#import "ShowStores.h"
#import "StoreDetail.h"
```

code where i load the next view when the user selects the cell,

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
StoreDetail *storedetail = [[StoreDetail alloc] init];
storedetail.storeImage = cell.imageView.image;
storedetail.storeCode = cell.textLabel;
storedetail.storeCode.text = cell.textLabel.text;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:storedetail animated:YES];
}
```

I have debugged it and the `cell.textLabel.text` and `cell.imageView.image` are not nil or null.
The second view loads but is black. I have set up a back button on the second view which takes the user back to the first view and that works fine.

Comment: in your StoreDetail what interface you are using?

Comment: I have synthesized the corresponding properties. My assumption is as i have already instantiated the properties i would not be requiring an 'interface'. NSLog(@" In StoreDetail %@",self.storeCode.text) in  viewDidLoad() does show that the values from the first form is passed. I guess the trick is linking that to the UILable and the UIIMage

Comment: Instead of UIImage or UILabel use NSString to fetch the data from the store page . Then on detail page use corresponding NSString to pass the data on label and image.

Comment: Thanks for the input @NoviceDeveloper but as i stated i do get the data successfully to the next view but the question is why is the second view controller black. I can't view either object as if they weren't there.

Comment: have u created a nib file for second view controller? If you did then use ....StoreDetail *storedetail = [[StoreDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"yournibname" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 0):

UIImage and UILabel don't conform to NSCopying protocol, that's most probably the reason. And so declaring @property (nonatomic, copy) doesn't do any effect as your intention.

My suggestion is setting retain for them, and at the point where you want to make copies, just initialize and assign the objects to them.

Comment: The issue if i can call it that is in this line of code: StoreDetail *storedetail = [[StoreDetail alloc] init]; This instantiates a whole new class doing away with the design i had done on the storyboard for this view controller which i have now changed to a tableviewcontroller but with a UIIMageView and a cell. It does show but image and the value passed from the first view controller but again the design is overridden which makes sense. Is there a way to do this without losing my design?

Answer (score 0):

do you have a nib for your second view controller with the storeCode uiLabel in? 
or are you creating the storeCode UILabel programmatically in viewDidLoad?

I would remove this line:

```
   storedetail.storeCode = cell.textLabel;
```

in this line:

```
   storedetail.storeImage = cell.imageView.image;
```

storeImage is a UIImage when I think you want it to be a UIImageView. (I would remove that line too and create a storeImageView the same way as you create the storeCode uiLabel - either have it in your nib or create it programmatically in viewDidLoad.

EDIT:

create the objects in viewDidLoad as follows:

```
storeCode = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 120, 16)];
[self addSubview:storeCode];
```

For the image I would set the name of the image (filename or path) to an NSString property on your second view controller and then in viewWillAppear use the string to create the correct UIImage and then assign that UIImage to your UIImageView.

Comment: The codes you stated was my attempt to set the values for the two objects. I do not have a nib file and would prefer to do this programmatically. I do not have code to set in my viewDidLoad as again my assumption was the view would be loaded with the objects set at the time of design with values obtained at run time.

Comment: The issue seems to be with StoreDetail *storedetail = [[StoreDetail alloc] init ]; where the store detail is initiated to a new instance and so overrides my design. Setting up a new UIViewcontroller programmatically in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method works where i can set the color etc and so the issue seems to be with the store detail class and the way it is initiated. I do not want to set up my view programatically as i have already done the design on the storyboard. If a nib file is the only way to go about it do direct me on how to create one in Xcode 4.2. Much appreciated.